# Multiline variable assignment speed and flux

Tags: python, performance, variables, python-2.7

So I was taking a look at the speed of variable assignment using the timeit module, and I came across some very interesting results. I have come to find out that the multi-line assignment is generally faster then single-line assignment. Why is this?

Also, it is notable that when putting `time.sleep(1)` in the loop below, it seems to affect the speed results ***significantly***. Why is this?

My code and results below:

***Without*** time.sleep:

```
dis results for myfunc1:
  5           0 LOAD_CONST               2 ((10, 10))
              3 UNPACK_SEQUENCE          2
              6 STORE_FAST               0 (x)
              9 STORE_FAST               1 (y)
             12 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             15 RETURN_VALUE        
dis results for myfunc2:
  7           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (10)
              3 STORE_FAST               0 (x)

  8           6 LOAD_CONST               1 (10)
              9 STORE_FAST               1 (y)
             12 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             15 RETURN_VALUE        


Speed results for single line assignment:
4.61830006532e-06
4.10515561362e-06
4.10515561362e-06
4.61830006532e-06
4.61830006532e-06
4.10515561362e-06
4.10515561362e-06
4.10515561362e-06
4.10515561362e-06
4.10515561362e-06
4.10515561362e-06


Speed Results for multi-line assignment:
4.10515561362e-06
3.59201116192e-06
4.10515561362e-06
3.59201116192e-06
4.10515561362e-06
3.59201116192e-06
3.59201116192e-06
4.10515561362e-06
4.10515561362e-06
3.59201116192e-06
4.10515561362e-06
```

***With*** time.sleep:

```
dis results for myfunc1:
  5           0 LOAD_CONST               2 ((10, 10))
              3 UNPACK_SEQUENCE          2
              6 STORE_FAST               0 (x)
              9 STORE_FAST               1 (y)
             12 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             15 RETURN_VALUE        
dis results for myfunc2:
  7           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (10)
              3 STORE_FAST               0 (x)

  8           6 LOAD_CONST               1 (10)
              9 STORE_FAST               1 (y)
             12 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             15 RETURN_VALUE        


Speed results for single line assignment:
4.61830006532e-06
5.13144451708e-06
9.03134234993e-05
0.000157022202221
8.77477012411e-05
4.61830006504e-06
4.7722434009e-05
1.59074780033e-05
0.000105707757051
0.000324307293475
1.43680446492e-05


Speed Results for multi-line assignment:
1.33417557446e-05
0.000202692058421
1.33417557446e-05
0.000163693080093
1.3854900196e-05
1.3854900196e-05
0.000279663726175
0.000142141013121
0.000202692058423
0.000200639480614
0.000103655179245
```

**Code**:

```
import dis,timeit,time

#define the different methods of assignment
def myfunc1():
    x,y=10,10
def myfunc2():
    x=10
    y=10

#used simply for viewing how they are assigned
print "dis results for myfunc1:"
dis.dis(myfunc1)
print "dis results for myfunc2:"
dis.dis(myfunc2)

print "\n"

print "Speed results for single line assignment:"
#repeat 10 times, with looping 100 times per repeat to show speed and consistency
for x in range(11):
    print timeit.timeit(stmt="x,y=10,10",number=100)
    #time.sleep(1)
print "\n"

print "Speed Results for multi-line assignment:"
#repeat with the same method for previous test
for x in range(11):
    print timeit.timeit(stmt="x=10;y=10;",number=100)
    #time.sleep(1)
```

Benchmarked on: `Python 2.7.3 (default, Apr 10 2012, 23:31:26) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32`

Comment: Why this convoluted benchmarking code which has a dozen places where subtle errors can sneak in? Why not just measure with `python -m timeit`? (Note though: I also measure a slight difference, with Python 3.3: 0.0482µs for `x,y=10,10` and 0.0378µs for `x=10;y=10`.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have come to find out that the multi-line assignment is generally faster then single-line assignment. Why is this?

Because `UNPACK_SEQUENCE` is slower than `LOAD_CONST`.

> Also, it is notable that when putting time.sleep(1) in the loop below, it seems to affect the speed results significantly. Why is this?

Because 100 iterations is too low count for that fast operation and is highly affected by the (low) clock precision. Re-test with `number=10000000` and you will get roughly the same results regardless of the sleep.